# Поворот текста в DataGridView MVVM WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagridview, текст, rotation

Делаю таблицу которая "растёт" по содержимому не "сверху вниз" а "слева на право"
Пытаюсь использовать для этого DataGridView ( в **MVVM** & **WPF**)
Имеется во View возможность поворота самого контрола на 90 градусов 
Вопрос : 
Как сделать так, чтобы и текст таблицы поворачивался бы тоже на те же 90 градусов (но уже обратно по отношению к контролу)
причём ***весь*** текст а не только Header.
(UPD:)
Хотелось бы сделать так, чтобы осуществлялся поворот таким образом что ,несмотря на то что таблица «легла» горизонтально , текст при этом оставался бы в обычном состоянии.На выходе -> таблица в горизонтальном – текст в «вертикальном» состоянии

Answer (score 0):

Повернуть можно целиком весь контрол, тогда все внутри(текст, header) соответственно тоже повернется.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsVM}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          ColumnWidth="*" 
          RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <DataGrid.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform/>
            <SkewTransform/>
            <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
            <TranslateTransform/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </DataGrid.RenderTransform>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="A" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="B" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="C" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```